# SymPy equivalent to HoldForm in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, sympy

In Mathematica, it is possible to prevent the system from simplifying expressions when they are entered. The syntax is as follows:

```
HoldForm[x/x]
```

Is it possible to do something similar with SymPy?

Answer (score 2):

The following approaches achieve a similar effect. There might be others available I am not aware of.

```
import sympy as sp

x = sp.symbols('x')

expr1 = x/x 
expr2 = sp.S('x/x', evaluate=False)
expr3 = sp.Mul(x, 1/x, evaluate=False)

print(expr1)
print(expr2)
print(expr3)
```

> ```
> 1
> x/x
> x/x
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `with evaluate(False)`, like

```
with evaluate(False):
     print(x/x)
```