# How to inhibit evaluation of functions in sympify?

Tags: sympy

sympify('atan(sqrt(3))') returns pi/3. Same thing for sympify with the 
evaluate = false tag.

Is it possible to convert the 'atan(sqrt(3))' string to the atan(sqrt(3)) sympy object ?

This is required for online math tests : if a question is 'what is atan(sqrt(3)) ?', the answer 'atan(sqrt(3))' is not acceptable, thus should be distinguishable from 'pi/3'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40367114/6212875) by @asmeurer:

```
import sympy as sp

with sp.evaluate(False):
    phi = sp.atan(sp.sqrt(3))

print(phi)
```

> `atan(sqrt(3))`